# How to update table with ORDER BY in the same table?

Tags: mysql

```
UPDATE post
SET body = 'hello'
WHERE post_id in (
  SELECT post_id from post WHERE user_id = '79' ORDER BY date DESC
);
```

I need to update some column in this table by select `post_id` from the same table but I can't why? And how can I solve this problem? 
Please help me, thank you.

```
post_id | user_id | body  | picture | date
1       | 79      | test  | null    | 2015-08-15 09:19:15
2       | 79      | test2 | null    | 2015-08-15 10:10:18
```

same like this

Comment: I think you should clarify your question better. Do you need to update only the last post in which user_id = 79 appeared?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you only want to update the last post of user_id = 79.

```
UPDATE
  post
SET
  body = 'hello'
WHERE
  user_id=79
ORDER BY date DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Please see a fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e89f84/1).

Answer (score 3):

That query makes absolutely no sense. You don't have to use subquery here, just update user posts by `user_id` field.

```
UPDATE post SET body = 'hello'
    WHERE user_id = 79;
```

Comment: this table have user_id and post_id column but if I update by Where only user_id the query will update all post that have user_id like 79 @Elon Than

Comment: @Drew it's definitely true

Comment: I was agreeing with you @ElonThan

Comment: @Peter, first off, let's not say like 79, rather =79 (or a string, whatever). Secondly, **what else is someone to think** from your query in the Question. So why don't you explain it better in the Question, and Elon will probably do whatever is necessary in like 1 minute